# Running an ed script from within ed

Tags: shell-script, ed

I have created a script file called "cleanup" which contains a series of regular expressions that clean up an ed file(s) of blank spaces, trailing white-space, blank lines etc. I run it as follows:

```
ed [name-of-file] < [name-of-script]
```

I sometimes want to run the script on the file I am currently editing from within ed. I am unsure of the syntax I would need to do that.

Here is an example script:

```
g/^  */s///
# Remove blank spaces at the beginning of a line
g/  *$/s///
# Remove trailing whitespace at end of line
g/   */s// /g
# Remove additional spaces between words
g/^$/d
# delete blank lines
g/\(‘‘\|’’\)/s//"/g
# Remove curly braces
g/\(“\|”\)/s//"/g
g/\(‘\|’\)/s//'/g
# idem
,p
Q
```

Comment: Does the script _output_ the edited file to standard output? If so, just editing the output would be easy with `e !ed -s % <script`.

Comment: `cat cript | ed - file`

Comment: @nezabudka this unfortunately does not work for me. Can you provide more information?

Comment: @devcom, Could you update the thread and add an example script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could possibly use

```
e !ed -s % <script
```

if the script ends with outputting the modified editing buffer, i.e. if the script ends with `,p` and `Q`.  This would replace the contents of the current editing buffer with the output of the command after `!`.  The `%` in the command will automatically be replaced by the current file's name (this command will not change the name of the current file).

Just remember to `w` first so that the spawned `ed` sees your edits up until that point.

(This does not seem to apply to your example script, but...) If the script does in-place editing of the file so that the file is saved back to disk at the end, then use

```
!ed -s % <script
e
```

This executes your `ed` command in a shell and then replaces the current editing buffer with the updated file contents.  Again, do not forget to `w` first.

---

Further explanation:

The `e !somecommand` command discards the current editing buffer and replaces it with the output of `somecommand`.

This means that `e !ed -s % <script` would be appropriate if the `script` editing script outputs the final result on standard output, and you would like to edit that output.

The `e` command, with no further argument, re-opens the current file and replaces the editing buffer with that file's content.  If this is preceded by `!somecommand` where `somecommand` *changes the current file*, then this is how you incorporate those changes into the editing session.

This means that `!ed -s % <script` followed by `e` would be what you may want to use if the `script` editing script saves the modified document back to the same name (rather than writing it to standard output).

Comment: Can you explain the significance of the different positions of `e' in these commands.

Comment: @devcom See added text.

Comment: I am very grateful to you for this explanation. Thank you.