# Is there a way to delete two non-juxtaposed duplicate lines in ed?

Tags: regular-expression, ed

I was looking for a way to delete non-juxtaposed duplicate lines in ed such as,

```
ed is a terminal editor
sam is a bitmap editor
emacs is a macro editor
ed is a terminal editor
```

I am hoping to produce:

```
ed is a terminal editor
sam is a bitmap editor
emacs is a macro editor
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [another case](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/658371/116858) where it's easier to call an external tool to do the work and then edit the output of that tool:

```
$ ed file
95
,n
1       ed is a terminal editor
2       sam is a bitmap editor
3       emacs is a macro editor
4       ed is a terminal editor
e !awk '!seen[$0]++' %
awk '!seen[$0]++' file
71
,n
1       ed is a terminal editor
2       sam is a bitmap editor
3       emacs is a macro editor
```

The `awk` command called via `e !` here outputs lines that have not been seen before, and will ignore lines that have been seen.  You will find examples of this specific use of `awk` in a number of answers on this site (e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30178/116858), and with explanation [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159695/how-does-awk-a0-work)).